# Multithread Making the application waitng for long time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to fetch 1000000 records from a database, so I am fetching records in a loop 1000 records at a time and union with the main collection. Getting 1000000 records in slices of 1000 records at a time is taking a long time. During this time I need to do another work in the application, but my application is waiting all this time (more than 1 minute).

Can you please give me a hint what can I make to take the work of the main thread?

```
 private void btnExrtPDF_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsOrSummary == "Details")
            isDetails = true;  
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FetchRecord));
        thread.Start();
    }
 private void FetchRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                if (DetailsOrSummary == "Details")
                    isDetails = true;

                long NoOfRecords = 1000;
                long toFetchRecords = 1000;
                DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
                long RecordsIcrease = 1000;
                PageIndex++;

                for (long k = toFetchRecords; k < DetailReportFCBuySell.FirstOrDefault().TotalRecords; k = +toFetchRecords)
                {

                    new AlxServiceClient().Using(channel =>
                    {
                        ObservableCollection<DLReports.FCBuySellDetail> temp = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);
                        DetailReportFCBuySell = DetailReportFCBuySell.Union(temp).ToObservableCollection();
                        PageIndex++;
                    });
                    toFetchRecords = toFetchRecords + RecordsIcrease;
                }

                ResultsData = DetailReportFCBuySell.ToDataTable();// (Collection.Where(i => i.Key == k).FirstOrDefault().Value);
                ExportToOxml(true);
            }
            else
            {
                //Other wise re-invoke the method with UI thread access
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => FetchRecord()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: any one please help. first time am using the threading, i tried more than 50 examples nothing give me a gud solution

Comment: What is ThreadStart? A runnable?

Comment: Why are you doing `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }`?

Comment: You should use `Async Await` if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the working thread you are checking if you are in the UI thread, else you use the dispatcher to execute the method in the UI thread. So from the UI thread you start a working thread to execute some work, which checks if it is in the UI thread, and if not, invoke itself on the UI thread.

It is this pattern:

```
private void FetchRecord()
{
    // try omitted...
    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        // do work...
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => FetchRecord()));
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem logical to me.

I think the solution would be not to check with the Dispatcher. Why are you doing that?

Another observation: please remove the try-catch if you are not going to add anything to it. As it is, it is useless.

### Update from chat:

You need to separate the non-UI logic from the UI logic. In this case you need to create some fields to store UI values, which you can use in the worker thread. Like this:

Private fields:

```
private DateTime _editStartDate; 
private DateTime _editEndDate;
```

Set them before you start the worker thread:

```
_editStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date; 
_editEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date; 
// now start the thread
```

And use them in the method that runs in the worker thread.

```
DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(
    transactionName, 
    isDetails, 
    _editStartDate, // use the field
    _editEndDate,   // use the field
    Customerid, 
    ProductID, 
    branchID, 
    NoOfRecords, 
    PageIndex - 1, 
    isBuy
);
```

Comment: when i remove the dipacher it shows  the following error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Comment: That is because you access UI elements, that is only allowed on the UI thread. You should split the code in a part that does access UI elements, and a part that does not access UI elements. Only the latter can be done in the working thread.

Comment: For example, this: `dtpEditEndDate.EditValue` (and others like it) should be done in the UI thread, so you have to do that before you start the working thread, and use either method-parameters, or fields to transfer those values to the worker thread.

Comment: "DetailReportFCBuySell = AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL(transactionName, isDetails, Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdtStartDate.EditValue).Date, Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEditEndDate.EditValue).Date, Customerid, ProductID, branchID, NoOfRecords, PageIndex - 1, isBuy);" this cause the error , it means it AlyexWCFService.DL.DLTTIn.FCBuySELL is already invoked during the application start , so it makes the crossthreadException. so, how can i avoid this crossthreadexception

Comment: Create a field for each `control.EditValue`, set the value of the field before starting the thread, and in the `FetchRecord` method use the field-value instead of the `control.EditValue`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122368/discussion-between-swetha-vijayan-and-maarten).